# Why can't the extended glob */ be negated with !(*/)?

Tags: bash, wildcards

In bash, if we activate the `extglob` shell option, we can do fancy stuff like negating a glob (from `man bash`):

```
   If  the  extglob shell option is enabled using the shopt builtin, sev‐
   eral extended pattern matching operators are recognized.  In the  fol‐
   lowing  description,  a pattern-list is a list of one or more patterns
   separated by a |.  Composite patterns may be formed using one or  more
   of the following sub-patterns:

          ?(pattern-list)
                 Matches zero or one occurrence of the given patterns
          *(pattern-list)
                 Matches zero or more occurrences of the given patterns
          +(pattern-list)
                 Matches one or more occurrences of the given patterns
          @(pattern-list)
                 Matches one of the given patterns
          !(pattern-list)
                 Matches anything except one of the given patterns
```

For example:

```
$ ls
a1file  a2file  b1file  b2file

$ shopt -s extglob
$ ls !(a*)
b1file  b2file
```

Now, if I want to do something to directories only, I can use `*/`:

```
$ ls -F
a1file  a2file  adir/  b1file  b2file  bdir/

$ ls -d */
adir/  bdir/
```

However, the glob `*/` apparently cannot be negated:

```
$ ls -Fd !(*/)
a1file  a2file  adir/  b1file  b2file  bdir/
```

What gives? Why doesn't `!(*/)` exclude directories when `*/` correctly includes only directories? And is there a way to exclude directories using globs in bash?

The above commands were tested using GNU bash, version 5.1.8(1)-release on an Arch Linux system.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because globs don't cross `/` boundaries. Except for the special case of `**/`¹ (originally from `zsh`, [now also found in a few other shells](/a/62665) often after setting an option (`shopt -s globstar` for bash)), a glob operator cannot match something that contains a `/` as they are applied on a directory listing.

The shell splits a `x/y/z` glob on `/`s. For each component, if the component contains glob operators, the shell lists the parent directory and matches the pattern again each entry, and if not, it just looks for that file with `lstat()`².

You'll see `a*b/c` won't match on `a/b/c`. The shell is only matching `a*b` against the entries in the current directory. Even `[a/b]*` is treated as `[a` and `b]*` separated by a `/`.

`*/` is `*` and nothing separated with `/`. It's a special case of `*/x` where the shell first looks for all the files that match `*` in the listing of the current directory, and then for each, try to see if a file called `file/x` exists (using `lstat()` in that case, not listing directories as `x` does not contain glob operator). With `*/` it's the same except it checks if a `file/` exists (which is only true if `file` is a directory or symlink to directory).

If you use `/` inside the ksh-style `@(...)`, `!(...)`... extended operators (a subset of which is available in `bash -O extglob` or `zsh -o kshglob`), the behaviour varies between shells, but will generally not do what you want as patterns in a glob are only ever matched against file names in a directory listing. In `bash`, `!(*/)` matches every (non-hidden) filename, likely because here that glob wasn't split on `/`, and the `*/` is checked in reverse against each directory entry name, and a directory entry name can't contain a `/`. That doesn't really explain why `!(*[a/b]*)` still includes filenames that contain `a`s or `b`s or why `!(*[a")"/b])` excludes filenames containing `a`s but not those containing `)`s or `b`s.

If you want files that are not determined to be of type *directory* after symlink resolution, that's not something you can do with globs alone, you'd need to use `zsh` and its glob qualifiers which can truly selects files base on attributes other than their name:

```
print -rC1 -- *(-^/)
```

Here, zsh matches the glob, and then applies the qualifiers as an extra step after globbing. Here `-` specifies that the following qualifiers are to be applied after symlink resolution (`stat()` instead of `lstat()`), `^` negates the following qualifiers, `/` selects files of type *directory*.

With `bash` 4.4+, you can always outsource the job to something else that prints the result NUL-delimited and use `readarray -td ''` to get the result, like:

```
readarray -td '' files < <(zsh -c 'print -rNC1 -- *(N^-.)')
(( ${#files[@]} )) && ls -Fd -- "${files[@]}"
```

Or with GNU `find` and `sort`:

```
readarray -td '' files < <(
  LC_ALL=C find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 \
    ! -name '.*' ! -xtype d -printf '%P\0' | sort -z)
(( ${#files[@]} )) && ls -Fd -- "${files[@]}"
```

(here sorting with `sort` so as to get the same list as with `zsh`, though for the special case of passing that list to `ls`, it's redundant as `ls` does its own sorting).

While you have a NUL-delimited list, you might as well skip the array step and pass the output to `xargs -r0 ls -Fd --` instead, which would avoid having to treat the empty list case specially and works around the *arg list too long* limitation.

---

<sup>¹ Though see also the `~` extendedglob operator in `zsh` that can be applied as an extra step after the full glob to filter out paths and match across `/`s. In `a*/b*/c*~*e*`, the filename generation algorithm is performed for the `a*/b*/c*` glob, and then  the resulting pathnames are filtered out with with the `*e*` pattern.</sup>

<sup>² case insensitive globbing can alter that though like with `zsh -o nocaseglob`</sup>

Comment: Why zsh's `**/` specifically? Ksh and bash's `**/` also matches recursively. You might quibble as to whether that means matching multiple components or matching “something that contains a /” but I don't understand what distinction you're making. You might also want to mention zsh's `~` which kind of doesn't-match on multiple components.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil', thanks for the feeback. See edit.

Comment: If `*/` means "the shell first looks for all the files that match `*`" and "then checks if a file/ exists", then why can't it do the opposite and check if a `file/` does _not_ exist? The negated `!(*/)` doesn't need to cross a `/` boundary any more than the `*/` does.

Comment: And is there really no way of excluding directories using globs only _in bash_?

Comment: @terdon I believe the point is that, in `!(*/)`, `*/` is not a globbing pattern, but a filepath including the `*` pattern. `extglob`'s expressions expect just a globbing pattern (list) inside the parentheses: `?(*/)`, `*(*/)` etc. match nothing too.

Comment: The shells don't seem to split on every `/`, as just giving `echo !(*[a/` waits for a continuation line. On the face of it, I would have assumed `!(*/)` compares filename components on that level against the pattern `*/`, which they won't match. But the way `!(*[a")"/b])` works doesn't really fit that. Looks to me `!([ax/b])` also matches `b` and `c`, but not `a`. (??)

Comment: @ilkkachu, yes the thing to take from that is that `/` there is not supported and unexpected triggering unspecified behaviour. Like I said, you'll find much variation between shells (and likely between shell versions), but in any case, what the OP wants to do cannot work unless the filename generation algorithm is reworked to come up with a different way to find files when `/` is found inside those extended `X(...)` operators.